# calculated rows with logic and append to data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

| Type | Name | Date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC | J | 1/31/2021 | 30 |
| AP | J | 1/31/2021 | 10 |
| AP | Q | 1/31/2021 | 10 |
| AC | Q | 1/31/2021 | 20 |

......1000 rows

I am trying to append rows type named AF to the dataframe based on the logic:
for same name and date, the amount of type AC - the amount of type AP

the expected result is as below:

| Type | Name | Date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AC | J | 1/31/2021 | 30 |
| AP | J | 1/31/2021 | 10 |
| AP | Q | 1/31/2021 | 10 |
| AC | Q | 1/31/2021 | 20 |
| AF | J | 1/31/2021 | 20 |
| AF | Q | 1/31/2021 | 10 |

I tried multiple ways even with pivot in python but still not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for reshape, so possible create new column by `subtract`, for original format use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Name','Date'], columns='Type', values='amount', aggfunc='sum')

df1['AF'] = df1['AC'].sub(df1['AP'])
df1 = df1.stack().reset_index(name='amount').reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Type Name       Date  amount
0   AC    J  1/31/2021      30
1   AP    J  1/31/2021      10
2   AF    J  1/31/2021      20
3   AC    Q  1/31/2021      20
4   AP    Q  1/31/2021      10
5   AF    Q  1/31/2021      10
```

If ordering is important use similar solution like another answer (now deleted) aggregate `sum`, subtract with [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), add new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original DataFrame:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Date', 'Type']).sum()

df1 = df.append(df1.xs('AC', level='Type')
                   .sub(df1.xs('AP', level='Type'))
                   .assign(Type='AF')
                   .reset_index(), ignore_index=True)
print (df1) 
  Type Name       Date  amount
0   AC    J  1/31/2021      30
1   AP    J  1/31/2021      10
2   AP    Q  1/31/2021      10
3   AC    Q  1/31/2021      20
4   AF    J  1/31/2021      20
5   AF    Q  1/31/2021      10
```